# Private Route with React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have built a CRUD application with react, redux and react-router. Application is redirecting to `/login`, if page is refreshed from PrivateRoutes. I am updating login status of user by fetching data from `localStorage` and dispatching action to update redux in App component.

App.js

```
const updateLoginStatus = () => {
  if (checkIfUserLoggedIn()) {
    const user = getLoginInitialState();
    dispatch(updateLoginInitialState(user));
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  updateLoginStatus();
}, [login.isLoggedIn]);
```

Routing in App component

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout}></Route>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/expenses" component={ListExpensesComponent} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/expenses/add-expense" component={AddExpenseComponent} />
    <PrivateRoute
      exact
      path="/expenses/edit-expense/:expense_id"
      component={EditExpenseComponent}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
const login = useSelector((state) => state.loginReducer);
return (
  <div>
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (!login.isLoggedIn) {
          return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        }
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }}></Route>
  </div>
);
```

One solution I found is

- adding one more action in login `UPDATE_LOGIN_REQUEST` and add `loading` property in login Reducer and set `loading: true` . Thus, displaying `<Loader />` until login status is updated.

Is there any other way we can handle it? Thanks in advance.